# Find number of shortest paths in an unweighted, undirected graph using adejacency-matrix

Tags: algorithm, octave, graph-theory, path-finding, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to write an algorithm that takes an adjacency-matrix A and gives me the number of shortest paths between all pairs of nodes from length 1 to 20. For example, if there are 4 nodes that have a direct neighbor and 2 nodes that are connected by a shortest path of length two (and no paths longer than 2) the algorithm should return a vector [4 2 0 ... ].

My Idea is to use the fact that A^N gives to number of paths of length N between nodes.

Here is how my code looks so far:

```
function separations=FindShortestPaths(A)

#Save the original A to exponentiate 
B = A; 

#C(j,k) will be non-zero if there is a shorter path between nodes j and k                               
C = sparse(zeros(size(A)));

n = size(A,1);

#the vector in which i save the number of paths
separations = zeros(20,1);

for i = 1:20
    #D(j,k) shows how many paths of length i there are from j to k
    #if there is a shorter path it will be saved in C, 
    #so every index j,k that is non-zero in C will be zero in D.
    D = A;
    D(find(C)) = 0;

    #Afterwards the diagonal of D is set to zero so that paths from nodes to themselves are not counted. 
    D(1:n+1:n*n) = 0;

    #The number of remaining non-zero elements in D is the number of shortest paths of length i 
    separations(i) = size(find(D),1);

    #C is updated by adding the matrix of length-i paths.
    C = C + A;

    #A is potentiated and now A(j,k) gives the number of length i+1 paths from j to k
    A = A*B;
endfor

endfunction
```

I tried it with some smaller graphs of length 5 to 8 and it worked (each pair is counted twice though) but when I tried it with a larger graph it gave me odd numbers for some lengths, which can't be right as every pair is counted twice.

Edit:

Here is an example of one of the graphs I tried and with which it worked: [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju9BX.png)
The adjacency Matrix of this graph is
[010000
101010
010101
001000
010000
001000]

And the number of shortest paths of length n from any Node is:

n: 1 2 3 4 5 6

A: 1 2 2 0 0 0

B: 3 2 0 0 0 0

C: 3 2 0 0 0 0

D: 1 2 2 0 0 0

E: 1 2 2 0 0 0

F: 1 2 2 0 0 0

---

Total: 10 12 8 0 0 0

So the algorithm should (and in this case does) return a vector where the first 3 elements are 10 12 8 and the rest are zeros. However, with [this bigger matrix](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3tTc-x6Bw8nZGdXY1JETDFxckE) it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't quite understand the requirements or the example from your phrasing. Is it that for every two nodes `a`, `b` in the graph you want to know how many paths of length <= 20 there are between `a` and `b`? If so then it sounds like you want to calculate `A +  A^2 + A^3 + ... + A^20`. If this isn't it then please include a picture of the graph in your example. Also note that these are not *shortest* paths.

Comment: @TomerGodinger For n<=20 I want to count for every node `a` the amount of nodes that are connected to `a` by a shortest path of length `n`. That's why my idea was to calculate A^n which gives me the number of paths of length n and then set all the values in A^n that have been non-zero in A^(n-1),A^(n-2),...,A to zero (using C) so the amount of indices with non-zero values that remain in A^n gives me the number of nodes that are connected by a shortest path.

Comment: OK, so in other words you want to know how many nodes are within a distance of at most 20 from `a` for each node `a` in the graph, right? In that case you can calculate (A+I)^20 then count the number of non-zero entries in each row (not counting the ones on the main diagonal). A+I represents the graph with added self-edges, so that would give you in (i,j) the amount of paths whose length is *at most* 20.

Comment: But frankly, it would be better to just run 20 iterations of BFS from each node and count the different nodes you reach. That would take O(n^2) as opposed to O(n^3) for the matrix multiplications (or O(n^2.373) if you put in some more effort). Well, technically, it would even be O(n), since you're limiting it to a constant number of iterations.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not quite what I meant. I am not looking for the number of **all** nodes that are within a distance of 20 from `a`. Rather I want to know how many nodes have a shortest path of length 1,2,3,... that leads to `a` for each number between 1 and 20. I hope you can see what I meant in the example that I gave in the edit: For example there is 1 shortest path of length from A to any other node (A-B) and 2 shortest paths of length 2 (A to C and A to E). If I am not mistaken (A+I)^20 would give me the number of all paths of length 20 - even those that aren't shortest paths.

Comment: That still sounds the same to me. (A+I)^20 will give you the number of paths whose length is **up to 20** from each node to the others. All the nodes for which this is more than zero are at most 20 nodes away, and therefore there exists a (shortest) path to them of length <= 20. If you only want to know the total (the sum) and not exactly how many there are for each length, (A+I)^20 works. I'm going to type an answer to demonstrate how it works on the examples you've provided.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed you wanted the vector for each length and not the total. My idea with (A + I)^20 wouldn't work for that, but the BFS idea will. The point of BFS is to mark the distance of each node from the source; count all the nodes with the same distance and you'll get the number you want for that source. Then sum up the numbers for the same distance across all nodes, put the results in a vector and you're done.